# Terrasync "GPS Disconnected" problem

Tags: gps, error, trimble, geoexplorer, terrasync

I have a GeoExplorer 6000 series handheld unit. I have a Terrasync 2.52 Serial key and installation disk.

I installed Terrasync 2.52 on the handheld unit but upon trying to connect to the receiver for 20 seconds, it says "GPS Disconnected" and never shows it connects to a satellite (COM 3 integrated GNSS Receiver is selected, all other settings default)

(also, under Setup, it says "GPS" instead of "GNSS" for some reason)

Arcpad uses the integrated receiver on COM 3 perfectly without issue.

I have also installed terrasync 2.53 with the exact issue. Any ideas?

Comment: this sounds like question for the customer support of either geoexplorer of terrasync.

Comment: Due to it being old software they say that they cannot provide help unless we upgrade

Comment: Your using quite old software and firmware https://www.trimble.com/globalTRLTAB.aspx?Nav=Collection-76117

Answer (score 1):

The first TerraSync version which supports the Geo 6000 internal GNSS receiver is TerraSync 5.10, so you need an update.  Older TerraSync versions running on Geo 6000 will connect to older external receivers via Bluetooth or via serial cable (with the USB to serial adapter).